# Reg Expression for Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have some URL paths in Google Analytics that I am trying to track with custom segments. Each path has a random integer in the middle, for example:

/applications/1985/edit
/applications/1986

I have tried to use the built in tools in GA to set up a segment that shows data for the path starting with /applications and ending with /edit but when I set it up this way I receive no data. When I set it up to show data where the path starts with /applications it shows data for all paths which i am trying to avoid.  I would like to be able to tell the difference between the two. I am thinking I need to use a regex to be able to distinguish between the two.

Can anyone provide an example regex that would allow me to track the links seperately?

I also have some other paths I need to track too but I might be able to figure those out with this example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

Starts with /applications/ followed by one or more numbers (a broad search, matching both the types of urls you showed in question):

`^/applications/([0-9+])`

Starts with /applications/ followed by one or more numbers nothing more except an optional trailing slash (matches only on your second example):

`^/applications/([0-9+])/?$`

Starts with /applications/ followed by one or more numbers and ending with edit and an optional trailing slash (matches on your first example):

`^/applications/([0-9+])/edit/?$`

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of simplicity...can you just use this?

^/applications/

If you need to specify the random integer in the path, use this:

^/applications/[0-9]+/

The plus sign will match one or more of the previous item, which is a number between 0 and 9.